# Azuma's inequality Use

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingale

For binary vectors, x = (x1,x2,...,xn) and y=(y1,y2,...,yn), the Hammond distance between them is defined by

d(x,y) = |x1 - y1| + |x2 - y2| + ... + |xn - yn|.

Let A be a finite set of such vectors and let X1, X2, ..., Xn be independent random variables that are each equally likely to be either 0 or 1. Set

D = min {d(x,y): (X,y) in A}. Find an upper bound for P(D >= b) in terms of E[D], when b > E[D].

I think we have to use Azuma's inequality but can't seem to figure out how..

Comment: It looks like you meant to refer to [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance).  A (simple) analysis of this distance distribution is at the heart of proofs of [Shannon's Source Coding Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%27s_source_coding_theorem), so perhaps you can get some ideas from studying those.  Out of curiosity, could you briefly say why you tagged this post with [tag:martingale]?